# Using the same class (model) to create two tables

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

im using SqlLite and .net core. How can i reuse the same class (Model) to create two table?

```
 public class Venda
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MasterID { get; set; }
        public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }

/* **********************************************  */

  public class MyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Venda> VendasRecebidas { get; set; } //Table one
        public DbSet<Venda> VendasTemp { get; set; } //Table two

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./mydb.db");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C# inheritance

```
public class VendaRecebida
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MasterID { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}

public class VendaTemp : VendaRecebida
{
}

/* **********************************************  */

public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<VendaRecebida> VendasRecebida { get; set; } //Table one
    public DbSet<VendaTemp> VendasTemp { get; set; } //Table two
```

Comment: it don't works for me, i just change my class VendaTemp  to abstract class and it works.

Comment: change class VendaTemp to abstract class VendaTemp to do your answer as correct.

Comment: You will not be able to create instances of `VendaTemp` if you mark it abstract

Comment: @LucasArgate Haven't tested myself but the situations I have used shared tables was when I create a common class with shared properties e.g VendaShared and then the two tables I want created inherit from this class like the class VendaTemp in the example.